# How to Get key value from parseJson()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a case that is how to find the **value** of a **key** that is in sekrip as follows:

```
JSON.parse({
    "data": [
        {
            "id_user": "351023",
            "name": "",
            "age": "29",
            "link": "http://domain.com"
        }
    ]
});
```

The above data was obtained from:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domain.com/target.php'></script>
```

I want to get the value of the key "id_user", anyone can help me?

Thanks before.

Comment: sorry, i will update code.

Comment: Your update still doesn't explain what `parseJSON` is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several issues here. Firstly, the method you're looking for is `JSON.parse()`, not `parseJSON`. Secondly, what you're providing to that function is already an object, not a JSON string, therefore it doesn't need to be deserialised as you can access it as you would any normal object:

```
var obj = {
    "data": [{
        "id_user": "351023",
        "name": "",
        "age": "29",
        "link": "http://domain.com"
    }]
}
console.log(obj.data[0].id_user);
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: this because yor description about "parseJSON"

Answer (score 3):

First its `JSON.parse`. Second it needs to be a JSON string.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5m5qs1x4/

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse('{"data": [{"id_user": "351023","name": "","age": "29","link": "http://domain.com"}]}');

document.getElementById('test').textContent = jsonData.data[0].id_user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse JSON string and than, access to keys/index

```js
var data = JSON.parse("{\"data\": [{ \"id_user\": \"351023\",\"name\": \"\",\"age\": \"29\",\"link\": \"http://domain.com\"}]}");

document.write(data["data"][0]["id_user"]);
```

Comment: This will error as the input to JSON.parse is a string, not an object.